# Will a Samsung Galaxy S6 case fit on an S6 Edge?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

The difference is size seems minimal but I want to make sure. Reason I ask is a custom printed case was ordered as a gift, modeled to fit a Galaxy S6, but the recipient has an S6 Edge. I am wondering if this will be an issue.

Edit:

The dimensions don't seem that far off.

Galaxy S6 Dimensions

(143.4 x 70.5 x 6.8 mm)

Galaxy S6 Edge Dimensions

(142.1 x 70.1 x 7 mm)

Comment: It may be an issue as the sides may be too high causing swiping on the curved edges to do certain gestures/actions would be difficult.  On the S7E that I have, the cases I've gotten all are slimmer on the sides to accommodate for the curved screen edges when swiping them.

Comment: @Oh Danny Boy...it's not a question of the dimensions, it's the fact that the screen on the Edge curves over the sides of the phone.  Cases made for the Edge take that into account, those made for the non-Edge do not.

Comment: Yes it would work but would be unpleasant

Answer (score -1):

All of the non-Edge versions of cases I've seen wrap around the sides which would cover the sides of the screen on the Edge.